# Handling Mobile app backend API domain change - iOS & Android

Tags: android, ios, networking

We have a mobile app that calls endpoints on host https://www.currentdomain.com. we are migrating to https://www.newdomain.com in a month

The network team is planning to setup a dns redirect from currentdomain to newdomain.
What is the best possible way to handle this change in the app with minimal change and work? What will happen if the app calls the endpoint on currentdomain after setting up the dns redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can support redirection in your APIs.I am not sure how much is it possible at your end but if yes, then no changes will be required at app side.

Otherwise http redirection can be handled easily by apps, like in iOS 1 method needs to be added & can redirect request to the desired url.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html

Redirect handler in android
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html